# Create Span on Each New Line in ContentEditable Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable, text-editor

I have one div which has contenteditable property true.
I want whenever new line is entered then that should be inside a span tag and that span should be inside p tag but whenever i am clicking on enter it just create new div.

**Initial**

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

**Entering this text**

1. some text
2. some new text
3. some more new text

**What i am getting**

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    some text
    <div>some new text</div>
    <div>some more new text</div>
</div>
```

**What i want**

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p><span>some text</span></p>
    <p><span>some new text</span></p>
    <p><span>some more new text</span></p>
</div>
```

How can i achieve above pattern using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by listening for the insertion of a line break and replacing it with the required elements, here is an example:

```js
const elm = document.querySelector('#ce');
elm.addEventListener('beforeinput', (event) => {
  if (['insertLineBreak', 'insertParagraph'].includes(event.inputType)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    const paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = '&#8203;';
    paragraph.append(span);
    elm.append(paragraph);
    
    const range = new Range();
    range.selectNode(span);
    range.setStart(span, 0);
    range.collapse(true);

    const selection = document.getSelection();
    if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
      selection.removeAllRanges();
    }
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
});
```

```css
#ce {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="ce" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Here, I'm using the `beforeinput` listener to check when a new line is inserted, I'm preventing that event `event.preventDefault()` and then,
I'm creating the required elements (a `<span>` inside a `<p>`) and I'm using the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) to set the caret inside the newly created `<span>`.

The only unusual thing here is this:

```
span.innerHTML = '&#8203;';
```

I'm using this because the caret will not be positioned correctly if the `<span>` doesn't have any content. `&#8203;` is a zero width space character.

There are probably better ways of setting the caret's position.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a need for the div to be initialized empty?

If not. You can already leave the initialized div with content with the formatting tags the way you want.
Ex:

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p><span>Some Text</span></p>
</div>
```

So each time a user inserts a newline, it will be with the formatting and content tags already present in the div.